# Passing Information through different modules Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, module

How can I store some values in a own created data Type. After the storing, different modules should have access to this values.

It would be nice, if you could show me some code example, because I'm quite new in Haskell

The code I have so far: 
**The second module(which does not have the main stuff)**

```
data SimuInfo = Information {
                massSaved:: Double
                } deriving Show

initialization::  Double-> SimuInfo
initialization m  = Information{
                      massSaved = m
                    }

--a example function, which uses the data
example:: Double -> SimuInfo -> Double
example a information = 2* a * b
                    where
                    b = massSaved information
```

**This is the code in the first module, which uses the data type:**

```
import Simufunc -- the import of the 2nd module



example2 :: Double -> Double
example2 a  = example a Information
```

**This is the following Error message I get:**

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘SimuInfo’
                with actual type ‘Double -> SimuInfo’
    Probable cause: ‘Information’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of ‘example’, namely ‘Information’
    In the expression: example a Information
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please limit Stack Overflow questions to focus on a single question. Your question about keyboard input should probably be moved to its own question, or [read up on input/output here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is informing you that `example2` is invalid because the second parameter you're passing to `example` is supposed to be a `Double` but you are instead passing a function.

```haskell
example2 a  = example a Information
```

`Information` is a constructor, which means that it is also a function that takes a `Double` as a parameter and returns a `SimuInfo` value.

You have an `initialization` function which does the same thing as the `Information` constructor: it is a function that takes a `Double` as a parameter and returns a `SimuInfo` value.

Therefore, you need to update `example2` to add that missing `Double` as input to `Information`. Here is an example of achieving this by adding another parameter to `example2`:

```haskell
example2 :: Double -> Double -> Double
example2 a infoVal = example a (Information infoVal)
```

The above could also be written using your helper function, `initialization`

```haskell
example2 :: Double -> Double -> Double
example2 a infoVal = example a (initialization infoVal)
```

If you want to have a "default" value for `SimuInfo` that you can access from anywhere (similar to a constant in other languages), you can declare it like so:

```haskell
zeroedInformation :: SimuInfo
zeroedInformation = Information 0
```